# How to write binary file in remote machine using j-interop?

Tags: java, j-interop

I am using J-interop and java to interact with window remote machine, I am able to connect to the remote window machine using j-interop but do not know how to write binary files to window remote machine. If any one have sample code to do that it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You already go through the docs? http://j-interop.org/sampleusage.html

Comment: Yes, I have already gone through all examples but have not found anything relevant to writing binary file.

Comment: You can try poking through the discussion area on sourceforge too: http://sourceforge.net/p/j-interop/discussion/ A bunch of questions on there that provide sample code

Comment: @MagicMan: They have not found any solution for this, all discussion ends up with same result(Exception), what I am getting while trying to write binary data in remote window machine.

Comment: Do anybody have solution for this....any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use another Java library then I would suggest you to look at JCIFS.  http://jcifs.samba.org/

I have success to use this library to perform file operations from a Linux node to Windows node (XP, 2003 Server, 7 and 2008 Server).

Good luck